# How to test loopback socket connections with python?

Tags: python, sockets

I want to test a complex class, which wraps some methods of the `socket` module:  `connect`, `sendall` and `recv`. Especially, I want to test the `recv` method of this class.

The working example code below shows how I could do that (in a basic, underlying form to keep it simple, `testsocket` would correspond to the complex wrapper class):

```
import socket

# This is just a socket for testing purposes, binds to the loopback device
sock =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
sock.listen(5)

# This is the socket later part of the complex socket wrapper.
# It just contains calls to connect, sendall and recv
testsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
testsocket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
testsocket.sendall("test_send")

# The testing socket connects to a client
(client, adr) = sock.accept()
print client.recv(1024)

# Now I can do the actual test: Test the receive method of the socket
# wrapped in the complex class
client.sendall("test_recv")
print testsocket.recv(1024)  # <--  This is what I want to test !!

# close everything
testsocket.close()
client.close()
sock.close()
```

But in order to test `testsocket.recv` I need to use `testsocket.sendall` before.

Is it possible to modify this code in a simple way (without forks or threads) in order to test `testsocket.recv` without using the method `testsocket.sendall`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  First, there is no error reported by you of the code as shown.  Second you don't give an example of what you mean by "test recv".  The code is somewhat odd, I'd expect a fork or thread to be used to run the client and server in seperate flows

Comment: I have updated the question a bit. The code works, but I wander if it can be accomplished with shorter code, just keep it simple. No fork and thread as well.

Comment: Ok, I rephrased the question completely. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`socket.socketpair`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socketpair)? :

```
import socket

client, testsocket = socket.socketpair()
client.sendall("test_recv")
print testsocket.recv(1024)
testsocket.close()
client.close()
```

**NOTE** only available in Unix.

---

Using [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)

```
import mock

testsocket = mock.Mock()
testsocket.configure_mock(**{'recv.return_value': 'test_recv'})
print testsocket.recv(1024)
```

Comment: I guess this is an acceptable answer. I just need to replace the `_socket` attribute of my class with `testsocket`, after which I can run the test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the client and the server socket in the same process/thread since the `server.recv()` is a blocking call

my routine :

```
import socket, threading

# Protocols supported
TCP = (0x00)
UDP = (0x01)
UDP_Multicast = (0x02)

# Client/ Server mode
CLIENT = (0x00)
SERVER = (0x01)

# Data to be sent
data = 'Test. Please Ignore'


# Server processing
def simple_processing(data):
    print "messsage : ", data


def start_socket( protocol, client, processing_callback):

    # switch on protocol
    if protocol == TCP:
        sock =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    else: 
        return

    # switch on client
    if client == SERVER:

        # Server mode = listening to incoming datas
        sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
        sock.listen(5)
        (sock, adr) = sock.accept()
        processing_callback( sock.recv(1024) ) # processing data

    elif client == CLIENT:

        # Client mode : connecting and sending data
        sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
        sock.sendall(data)


    else:
        return

    sock.close()


def test():

    # Thread creations
    server = threading.Thread( target = start_socket,
                               args=(   TCP,
                                        SERVER,
                                        simple_processing, )  
                              )

    client = threading.Thread(  target= start_socket, 
                                args=(  TCP,
                                        CLIENT,
                                        None)
                                )

    server.start()
    client.start()


    # Join : wait on every thread to finish
    client.join()
    server.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Launch the test
    test()
```